# ASP.NET MVC Core - Preventing multiple form submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm designing a time clock web app, where on the main page where the user can clock in/out if they have a current activity record or not (from a SQL server database)

I have the following form:

```
<form asp-action="RegisterClockAction" asp-antiforgery="false" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="ActiveFlag" type="hidden"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 offset-sm-1 center-column">
            <button id="clock-in-btn" type="submit" class="btn clock-button" disabled>Clock In</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 center-column">
            <button id="clock-out-btn" type="submit" class="btn clock-button" disabled>Clock Out</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then I have the following JavaScript for this specific View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        const activeFlag = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.ActiveFlag));
        if (activeFlag) {
            $("#clock-out-btn").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#clock-in-btn").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });

    $("form").submit(function() {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now the form submit event **does prevent from double submission, but is this the correct way I should be doing it?**

Not sure if it's necessary to know, but all the controller POST action does, if the active flag is true then we find the record in the database, update it and commit the changes to mark inactive. Otherwise, we create a new record to append into the database. Then, I just redirect back to the Index view to rebuild the model.

Comment: It's pretty common to have just a form there if it does what you need, from the user perspective it's better to have kind of spinner indicating loading in front of the form after submit.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I prefer ajax so that you can show spinners or loading gifs and prevent user action within the web page.

Comment: `Now the form submit event does prevent from double submission, but is this the correct way I should be doing it?`-What does double submission mean here?

Comment: I opted upon AJAX if you want to be more flexible during form submission, just simple `preventDefault()` on submit would suffice before using actual POST method and disable submit button to prevent multiple posting (by clicking submit button multiple times).

Comment: By double submission I mean, if I remove that piece of JavaScript code, if I spam "Clock In" button per-say, it will submit multiple POST requests, creating multiple database records.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by using **javascript**

you should use `event.preventDefault()` so that the default action of the event will not be triggered again.

```
 $("form").submit(function(e) { // 'e' <- add this line of code
     e.preventDefault(); // <- add this line of code
     if ($(this).valid()) {
        $(this).find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     }
 });
```